# What is meant with $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f: E \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $E$ is open. Let $x \in E$.

What is meant with $\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h)$? More precisely, over what values can $h$ range?

I think there are two possibilities:

(1) Put $V:= \{h \in \mathbb{R} \mid x+h \in E\}$. Then $h$ can range over $V$.

(2) Because $x \in E$, and $E$ is open, there is $r>0$ with $(x- \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subseteq E$, so $h$ can range over $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \subseteq E$.

Am I correct that when one writes $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)$, then one means either one of these two options?

It also seems that there is no ambiguity, because I managed to prove that

$$\lim_{h \to 0, h \in V} f(x+h) = \lim_{h \to 0, h \in (- \epsilon, \epsilon)}f(x+h)$$

Is all this correct?

Comment: Condition $(2)$ is just perfect over condition $(1)$ to choose $h$. Because you have to remember that $x+h \in E$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Note that $\exists f(x+h)\iff h\in V.$ However, when we consider $\lim_{h\to 0}$ we have to consider only "small" values of $h$ (that is, $h\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon).$

Comment: Limit is a local property. So these seem fine to me.

Comment: Nice approach of You, this is what we want for the composition of 2 functions i.e $f$ and $x+h$.Good job.

Comment: Correction: local concept.

Comment: Apart from some epsilon-delta-definition, you can also define $\lim_{x\rightarrow l} f(x)$ to be the value $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)$ where $x_i$ is any sequence converging to $l$ -- which is well-defined only if your function $f$ is continuous. You can then try to prove the equivalence of this with the epsilon-delta formulation and see which premises you need.